# imagej get current image from imagestack

Tags: imagej

i need to get the current image opened after importing an image sequence to ImageJ.
As i need to save the overlay information to a text file bearing the name of the image

```
int number = imp.getImageStackSize();
if(number > 1)
{
  ImagePlus check = imp.duplicate();
  gd.removeAll();
  gd.addMessage(check.getTitle());
  gd.showDialog();          
}
```

`imp.gettitle` returns the folder name the images were loaded from.

couldn't find any solution so far :(

Any way to find the text in the status bar would be appreciated..

Comment: is there anyway to get the string in the status bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a simple issue..
the name of the current image can be retrieved by the following piece of code..

```
fileName = imp.getImageStack().getShortSliceLabel(imp.getCurrentSlice());
```

Thanks everyone..